# Insert script and iframe tag in IE

Tags: javascript, window.open, childwindow

I want to write script and iframe elements in the opened window, which works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

My code is below:

```
 var mywindow = window.open(url,'child',params);
 mywindow.onload = writeToWindow;

 function writeToWindow(){
      var myScriptEle = document.createElement('script');
      myScriptEle.type = "text/javascript"; 
      myScriptEle.text = " some script";

      var myIframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      myIframe.id = "childwindow";
      myIframe.name = "childwindowname";
      myIframe.src = MyframeUrl;

      if(mywindow){
      mywindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myScriptEle);
          mywindow.document.body.appendChild(myIframe);
      }
 }
```

I'm getting "No such interface supported" errors

Thanks in advance, please let me know if there's any work around for IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mywindow = window.open(url,'child',params);
writeToWindow();

function writeToWindow(){
     var content = '<script type="text/javascript">';
     content += 'function updatePage(){ '; 
     content += 'var myiframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");';
     content += 'myiframe.id = "myIframe";';
     content += 'myiframe.name = "iframe_js";';
     content += 'myiframe.className = "iframe_js";';
     content += 'myiframe.src ="http://stackoverflow.com"';
     content += '</script>';
     if(mywindow){
          mywindow.document.open();
          mywindow.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+content+'</head><body onload="updatePage()"><div></div></body></html>');
          mywindow.document.close();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite easy, getElementsByTagName is not supported(well either that or it doesnt do what it should) in IE!

For things like this you're better off getting a library like jQuery. This will help you write code that will work on all browsers and won't cost you hours of your time figuring out why stuff doesn't work in browser x or y

Comment: thank for your reply, Is there any work around with out using Jquery??